# TextView from ViewPager is throwing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, textview, android-viewpager, nullreferenceexception

I have a fragment with a ViewPager inside it. In the ViewPager I have 4 content screens so swipe around in. The content has a few TextView components and I'm trying to access them from the first fragment, however when I go to use setText or similar I get a null pointer exception. Ive checked and the id for the TextView is valid, and I've done a clean build.

Here is a snippet of my relevant code:

```
private TextView textViewOne;

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager pager;
View rootView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_viewpager, container, false);

    InitializePaging();

    textViewOne = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.create_name);

    //would return null if I did this:
    textViewOne.setText("test");
    return rootView;
}

private void InitializePaging() {
    mPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getContext(), getChildFragmentManager(),
            Arrays.asList(PageOne.class, PageTwo.class, PageThree.class, PageFour.class));

    pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.content_pager);
    pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}
```

The PageOne class:

```
public class PageOne extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(container == null) {
        return null;
    }
        return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page_one, container, false);
    }
}
```

This is the fragment_layout_viewpager xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/content_pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `create_name` is inside `fragment_layout_viewpager ` ?

Comment: Post your *fragment_layout_viewpager* `Layout` code also.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK its witihin one of the mPagerAdapter page classes.. e.g. PageOne.class

Comment: @jaydroider added it.

Comment: @Indent Your *create_name* should be inside this `Layout`.

Comment: @jaydroider create_name is in PageOne.class.. which is one of the content pages that goes into the ViewPager

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating `fragment_layout_viewpager`, so the `create_name` should exist in that layout, otherwise it will throw a null pointer.

Comment: I see. How do I access components from within my PageOne class's  layout, etc?

Comment: Your fragments' layout should be inflated in the onCreateView. `fragment_layout_viewpager` should be the activity's layout.

Comment: See example here [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

Comment: I have many fragments within my activity, fragment_layout_viewpager is just one of the displayed fragments. fragment_layout_viewpager holds the ViewPager component. I then add the PageOne, PageTwo, etc to the ViewPager. I now want to access the components within PageOne, etc. So, I dont think thats the right answer

Comment: The code you have posted is of a fragment. You are initializing a viewpager inside a fragment and then putting more fragments in it? This is not how fragments work. Post your PageOne code so I can explain.

Comment: Move `findViewById(R.id.create_name);` into PageOne, PageTwo etc, then it will work. Also, the viewpager should be inside an Activity, not a fragment.

Comment: Ok, ill move them to there. How do I then access them from within the original fragment?

Comment: The logic for setting data in a textview should ideally be contained in the fragment that creates the textview. Otherwise you can write a method in your PageOne that returns the textview and then use it that way. You can obtain an instance of the fragment from your ViewPagerAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create an interface with 1 abstract method. Let the Fragment implement the interface and call the callback method from Activity.In the below example, I try to pass value on click of button from MainActivity to ThirdFragment.

public interface FragmentCommunicator { 
    public void passDataToFragment(String someValue);
 }

  public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button btn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button) ;
        btnsetOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              randomvalue= getRansomString();
                if(fragmentCommunicator!=null)
                fragmentCommunicator.passDataToFragment(randomvalue);
            }
        });
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }
    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {
                case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
                case 1: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
                default: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment,Instance 1");
}
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
    public static class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);
            tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));
            return v;
        }
        public static FirstFragment newInstance(String text) {
            Log.e("FirstFragment","newInstance called");
            FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("msg", text);
            f.setArguments(b);
            return f;
        }
    }
    public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentCommunicator {
    TextView tv;
    String value="";
    public FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator;
    @Override
    public void passDataToFragment(String someValue) {
        this.value = someValue;
        tv.setText(value);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {           
            ((MainActivity)activity).fragmentCommunicator = this;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement FragmentCommunicator");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);
        value=getArguments().getString("msg");
        tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);
        tv.setText(value);
        return v;
    }
    public static ThirdFragment newInstance(String text) {
        ThirdFragment f = new ThirdFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg",text);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }
}
```